# Harmonic Identity Evidence

Tags: number-theory, harmonic-numbers

I was recently cleaning up my laptop when I stumbled upon a spreadsheet that I created a while ago at school when I still had an interest in math. Anyway, I remember reaching the following identity using illegal methods on conditionally convergent series.

Let $f$ be an arithmetic function defined by:
$$f(n) = \sum_{d|n; \ \sqrt n\le d \le n}(-1)^d$$

Then,
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n*\frac{H_n}{n} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n} = \frac{6*ln^2(2) - \pi^2}{12}$$

where $H_n$ is the $n^{th}$ harmonic number.

[EDIT] Upon further research, I am 99% certain that the latter part of the above identity is true. It seems like an interesting result, however, I have no insight on its implications.

I cannot claim this to be true and, for all I know, it may be a useless statement, anyway. However, I found it interesting that $$\text{ if n is odd and composite, then }f(n) \lt -1 \text{ (trivial)}$$$$\text{if } f(n) \gt -1 \text{, then n is even. (trivial)}$$$$\text{ if n is odd and prime or 1, then } f(n) = -1 \text{ (trivial)}$$

[EDIT] It is actually the converse of the 2nd statement that is necessary to imply the other two converses. Sorry.

[Here](https://imgur.com/YC9n9Xa) are 3 graphs from my spreadsheet mentioned earlier. The first graph is of the difference between $\sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{f(n)}{n}  $ and $\frac{6*ln^2(2)-\pi^2}{12}$ for k up to 14000. The second and third graphs are of $f(n)$ for n up to 50 and 14000 respectively.(I do not have the reputation to post images, sorry!)

In these graphs it appears that $f(n)$ is random and growing very slowly in magnitude.

In conclusion, my questions are:

1. Can anyone see a way to (dis)prove the converse of the statement about $f(n)$ for even n?
2. Does anyone have references where I can find information about this from a more qualified standpoint?
3. Is this all just mathematical jibberish that I wasted my time on back in the day, or is there a reason to find it interesting that the identity appears true?

Thanks.

Comment: If your first and third statements (about the relative size of $f(n)$ and $-1$) really are if-and-only-if statements, then the second statement is trivially true, because it's the only case left.

Comment: Sorry those are both supposed to be "if". I'll fix it. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equality is certainly true (modulo some convergence justification):
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}n &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ \sqrt n\le d \le n}} (-1)^d \\
&= \sum_{d=1}^\infty (-1)^d \sum_{\substack{d\le n \le d^2 \\ d\mid n}} \frac1n \\
&= \sum_{d=1}^\infty (-1)^d \sum_{1\le m \le d} \frac1{md} \\
&= \sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^d}d \sum_{1\le m \le d} \frac1m = \sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^d}d H_d.
\end{align*}

If $n$ is even, then
$$
f(n) = \#\{ d\mid n,\,  d\text{ even},\, \sqrt n\le d \le n \} - \#\{ c\mid n,\,  c\text{ odd},\, \sqrt n\le c \le n \}.
$$
Moreover, every divisor $c$ of $n$ counted in the second set has a corresponding divisor $2c$ of $n$ counted in the first set; therefore the difference is definitely nonnegative, proving the desired converse. (The difference can certainly be positive: even divisors of $n$ between $\sqrt n$ and $2\sqrt n$ contribute to the first set but not the second, as do divisors of the form $4c$, $8c$, etc.)

As for the growth rate: when $n$ is odd (and, say, not a perfect square), then $f(n) = -\frac12d(n)$, where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$. And the maximal order of the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Approximate_growth_rate) is known. Something similar will be true for positive values.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks again for the help!